# Resetting / Modifying network configuration in Centos 7 Rescue mode

Tags: linux, centos, linux-networking, centos7, linux-kernel

I've a dedicated server `CentOS 7` and i made a wrong configuration for it

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp2s0`

So after restarting the network drive, the server went down ..

So i've a copy of the original file and want to reset it from `Rescue` mode . but the problem is i'm unable to reach `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` although of i mounted the disk

so how can I solve this problem using `Rescue` mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that i've to enter the correct path inside the mounted drive

```
/mnt/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
```